# What is the O of this operation?

Tags: big-o

Say for a given positive integer number `n`, you have to find a level `k` so that

`1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k = S` is below or equals `n`

but `S + k + 1` is above `n`.

For example in python:

```
def find_level(n):
    level = 1
    while n > 0:
        n -= level
        level += 1
    return level - 1
```

What is the O magnitude of this function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is O(...) and how do I calculate it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it)

Comment: Big Oh notation is simply a notation to concisely express the growth rate of a function. You are asking about the Big Oh notation, i.e. the growth rate of some function, but you are not actually telling us *what* function you want to know the growth rate of. Also, Big Oh notation has nothing to do with [softwareengineering.se], it is simple mathematics.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I just showed you the function (find level). Big-O is a software engineer related term.  FYI - arrogance is not very helpful.

Comment: `find_level` is not a function in the mathematical sense. It is an algorithm. Big Oh only works to describe the growth rate of mathematical functions. So, do you want to describe the growth rate of the function that is computed by the `find_level` algorithm?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: That seems like a distinction without a difference.  If what you consider the correct wording is "the growth rate of the function that is computed by the `find-level` algorithm," then yeah, that's what he wants.  I'm not a mathematician; I would call it "the Big O of the function," and would feel just fine doing so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: If that is indeed what the OP is asking, then it is important for the OP to clarify, since we *typically* use Big Oh notation for describing the growth rate of the computational complexity of an algorithm, not for the growth rate of the function that is computed by the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

1. Simplify:

   ```
   def find_level(n):
       level = 0
       while n > 0:
           level += 1
           n -= level
       return level
   ```
2. Get the closed form for the highest `n` per `level`:

   n = sum(x = 0 to level, x) = level * (level + 1) / 2
3. Solve that for `level` using [the quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) or some other method:

   0.5 * level<sup>2</sup> + 0.5 * level - n = 0

   level = -.5 + sqrt(.25 + 2 * n)

Your algorithm is obviously O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: If you're going to do that analysis though, why not just return the closed form for `level` and make the algorithm `O(c)`?

Comment: Well, I derived the closed form for `level` to determine the order of the given algorithm. The trivial step of actually using it *directly*, I leave to the observant reader. One just has to beware of the implementations limitations, regarding square-root and general floating-point.

Comment: @Deduplicator so your closed form is also O(sqrt(n))?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli No, Philip got it right.

Comment: @Deduplicator ok, cool. So I assume that finding sqrt of a number is an operation in constant time?

Comment: Depends on your model. But that's close enough for a 32 bit number, even though it's still a costly operation.