# Do I have do use HashTables/Maps/Hashmaps in this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, jvm

I am doing the Ransom Note algorithm in Hackerrank. The thing is I am not using maps and all the tests pass except for three which execution time takes a lot more. (Kotlin language)
I have two approaches:

**1 - Recursively**

```
fun checkMagazine(magazine: Array<String>, note: Array<String>): Unit {
    controlWords(magazine, 0, magazine.size / 2, note)
    controlWords(magazine, magazine.size / 2 + 1, magazine.size - 1, note)

    if (note.none { it.isNotEmpty() }) print("Yes") else print("No")
}

fun controlWords(magazine: Array<String>, start: Int, end: Int, note: Array<String>) {
    if (end - start < 1) {
        return
    }

    for (j in start..end) {
        if (note.none { value -> value.isNotEmpty() }) {
            return
        }
        if (note.contains(magazine[j])) note[note.indexOf(magazine[j])] = ""
    }
}
```

**And Iteratively:**

```
magazine.map {
        if (note.none { value -> value.isNotEmpty() }) {
            print("Yes")
            return
        }
        if (note.contains(it)) note[note.indexOf(it)] = ""
    }

    if (note.none { it.isNotEmpty() }) print("Yes") else print("No")
```

Obviously it pushes me to use maps, but can there be another solution, faster, without maps?

> Your code did not execute within the time limits

Comment: *Why* are you against using a map, the right solution for this problem?

Comment: No, nothing particular. I just wanted to see the result without hashmaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, you have an [O(n^2) algorithm](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it) - you have a loop (either explicitly in your recursive case or implicitly as part of `map` in the iterative case) which calls `contains`. `contains` has to iterate over the entire array to determine it's result, so it's going to be slow. A map has a lookup time of O(1) so will be a lot quicker.

Comment: A hashtable has lookup time of O(1), except in degenerate cases.

Comment: Ummm, yeah. You are of course right.

Comment: hmmm, what if i replace `contains` with `binarySearch`.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher That would make it a lot faster, assuming the array in question is sorted. Still might not be faster than a hash map.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher: Note that your repeated `note.none(…)` calls are also slow. They have to iterate over the entire `note` array in the worst case.