# Time complexity of a Nested While loop in a for loop

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I'm trying to derive the simplified asymptotic running time in Theta() notation for the two nested loops below.

```
For i <-- 1 to n do
    j <-- 1
    while j*j <= i
        j = j+1
```

```
For i <-- 1 to n
    j <-- 2
    while j <= n
        j = j*j
```

I have been trying to solve this using the summation method but not really getting the right answer. The picture below shows my attempts at the problem, I was able to get (n^3/2) for the first algorithm, however, I wasn't sure how to proceed with the second algorithm.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is O(...) and how do I calculate it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it)

Comment: Are you aware your second algorithm returns the same value every time? That doesn't fundamentally affect the question but it makes me wonder if you've got a typo somewhere.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: neither the first nor the second algorithms seems to *return* anything.

Comment: This site is not for solving other peoples homework. But I will give you a hint how you can solve this by yourself: start with some *examples* for different values of n, and lookup the basic calculation rules for logarithms.

Comment: Its just a practice problem that i'm having trouble with, i want to understand it first before going for my assignment @DocBrown. I am aware there is nothing returning, so the inside of each iteration should just be O(1) . I'm more interested in the Theta() of the nested loop it self. So for the second algorithm, i plugged in some n, but the loop will pretty much only run once.  So J^2 <= n, which means j <= root(n)?

Comment: @Freakup2: pick n=100000, or 1.000.000. How often does the inner loop run? Not "once", that's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### First algorithm

We iterate `n` times in the outer loop.  For every iteration `i`, the inner loop iterates from 1 to `sqrt(i)`, so `sqrt(i)` times. So the total number of iterations is:

```
 n
 ∑ √i
i=1
```

I spare you and me the [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1241903/708291), but the result can be approximated by the integral of `√n` which is `(2/3)*n^(3/2)`.  For very big numbers, this is mainly driven by the strongest polynomial factor, so the the complexity is `O(n^(3/2))`.

### Second alogrithm

#### If there's a typo and the while should be <= i

We iterate `n` times in the outer loop.  For every iteration `i`, the inner loop  iterates `k` times, where k is such that `2^k>i`.  `k` can easily be determined as  `log2(i)` so `log(i)/log(2)`.

so this time we have a total number of iteration of

```
 1      n
---- .  ∑ log(i)
log2   i=1
```

For the order of magnitude, we can ignore the constant coefficient and just look at the sum.  Again, sparing you (and me!) the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228748/708291),  the sum is `log(n!)`  which is approximated by `nlog(n)`

### If there is no typo and it's really <= n

Then you perform `n` times the same inner loop which is made of `log(n)/log(2)` iterations, so here the number of iteration is

```
 1      n             1
---- .  ∑ log(n)  = ---- . n log(n)
log2   i=1          log2
```

So it's exactly `O(nlog(n))`