# Running time for simple for loops - Big O notation

Tags: algorithms, big-o, algorithm-analysis

I am currently doing some exercises with algorithms and I find myself in a huge problem.

It seems that everybody understands this type of problem but I have a really hard time figuring it out. For exercise, we have some for loops to look at, and we need to figure out the runtime for that specific algorithm. We got a solution, which is great and all, but I do not really understand it.

Here is the code for you to look at:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int n = N; n > 0; n /= 2)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sum++;
```

And the solution for this algorithm is `O(n)`.

And for our task we need to figure out why the solution is `O(n)` (we need to write the Big O notation if you understand what I mean by that `0(1) + O(n)...` for example.)

I have found some explanation for this task on Stack Exchange but I do not understand it at all.
I am sorry if you think this is a stupid question but I just started studying software engineering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is O(...) and how do I calculate it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you need to prove the algorithm is `O(N)`, not `O(n)`.

- During the first iteration of the first `for` loop, the statement (`sum++`) is called `N` times.
- During the second iteration, it is called at most `N/2` times. (Here, unlike your algorithm, it's a division of floats.) Why at most? Well, if `N` is odd, `N/2` is rounded down, because `n` is an integer.
- During the third iteration, it is called at most `N/4` times.
- Etcetera, etcetera.

The *total* number of times the statement is called is (at most) `N` + `N/2` + `N/4` + ... which is `2N`. (The easiest way to visualize this is some sort of pie chart: half a pie + a quarter of a pie + ... = one pie.) So the algorithm is `O(2N)`, but multiplication by a constant is 'ignored' by big O notation; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant) for details.